# Access the title of a birt report in the master page

Tags: birt

I am new to birt and working with a report that has a master page. the inner report has a title property displayed in the XML as:

```
<text-property name="title"> title here.</text-property>
```

I want to access this value which will be different in every inner report and display it in the master page. I cant figure out how to access this value.

Answer (score 3):

Got this answer from a co-worker:

```
reportContext.getDesignHandle().getProperty("title")
```